# Contour plot in Mathematica with logarithmic scale

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

How can i plot a function with contour plot order and have at **logarithmic scale the function itself**, not the x and y axes!

Comment: try `ScalingFunctions->{None, None, "Log"}`?

Comment: F = ContourPlot[Function, {d, 0, 5}, {P, 0, 10},
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
  Contours -> 10,
  PlotRange -> {None, None, Log},
  PlotLegends -> All,
  FrameLabel -> {"d", "P"},
  PlotLabel -> "Function"
  ]

Comment: I need Function in logarithmic scale...nothing changes with ScalingFunctions

Comment: Nikitas, `ScalingFunctions->{None, None, "Log"}`, _**not**_  `PlotRange -> {None, None, Log}`.

Comment: Can I use ScalingFunction instead of PlotRange? Can i use both simultaneously or one of them cancels the other?

Comment: Simply try it !

Comment: Ok! Thanx for helping!